# sql server 2008: how do you set up a trace on a specific database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql, audit

i am trying to use sql server profiler to trace all the sql statements on a specific database, is this possible to do?

Comment: Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272730/sql-server-profiler-how-to-filter-trace-to-only-display-events-from-one-databas)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about SQL Profiler on a 2005 or 2008 server, you can do it by adding a column filter.  You will need to show all columns in the Events Selection tab.  Once you do that you should see an option for Database Name.